# How to serve a Bolero (F#) web app to the internet?

Tags: f#, bolero

I'm new to using web servers, and I'm trying to learn the Bolero (F#) web framework.  As a learning exercise, I'm trying to put the example app "into production", i.e. serve it to the internet and not just localhost.

I would like to use a basic (linux) web server to serve the website (specifically DigitalOcean)..i.e. not a specialized dotnet/microsoft/azure etc platform.

I don't believe that launching an app is covered in the documentation on the Bolero website (aside from a development setup using localhost).

I created the app with:

```
dotnet new bolero-app -o HelloWorld
```

Then after some web-searching I did:

```
cd HelloWorld
dotnet publish -c Release
```

Then if I do:

```
cd ./src/HelloWorld.Server/bin/Release/net6.0/publish
./HelloWorld.Server
```

I get the message:

```
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

I'm not sure if those steps are the way I should be going about this...I would like to be serving on port 80, but I've not been able to change that or find where this is set in the example project. I grepped the project for "5000" but couldn't find where that setting is.  I tried setting an environment variable with: "sudo export ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:80/". That hasn't changed where the app tries to serve the site. (Presumably I should be trying to write the server's ip address there instead of localhost?)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

---

EDIT: I've been able to serve the app to the internet!

From the main app directory (HelloWorld) I did:

```
cd /src/HelloWorld.Server 
sudo dotnet run --urls "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80/
```

...where the x's were replaced with my server's IP address.
)

Comment: For configuring the port on a self-hosted asp.net core web app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0 .

Comment: @chadnt - thanks for the link.  As I mentioned in the second last paragraph, I've tried to set an environment variable (as suggested in the link you sent), however that has not worked for me.  I have also tried to create a HelloWorld/Properties/launchSettings.json directory and file with the contents: {"Urls": "http://localhost:8000;http://localhost:8001"} as suggested in your link, however that has also not had an effect on the port that the app serves on (5000).